# no ajax complexion inside bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I create a modal and inside I insert an input field. When I write inside this input field a product name term, it must appear all the terms.

On blank page, I can see for ap (apple terms) all the apple products, no problem my ajax works fine

Now inside a page with some html element, I call a modal when there is my input fields. In this case, the ajax complexion does not work and inside the console log / result, I see my input field and not the result about my request.
I do not understand where my error below the result with a picture.

My modal call : works very fine

```
 <!-- Link trigger modal -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="<?php echo $this->getDef('text_select_products'); ?>" class="col-5 col-form-label"><?php echo $this->getDef('text_select_products'); ?></label>
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <a
            href="<?php echo $this->link('SelectPopUpProducts'); ?>"
            data-bs-toggle="modal" data-refresh="true"
            data-bs-target="#myModal"><?php echo '<h4><i class="bi bi-plus-circle" title="' . $this->getDef('icon_edit') . '"></i></h4>'; ?></a>
          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
               aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="te"></div>
                </div>
              </div> <!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
          </div><!-- /.modal -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="<?php echo this->link('modal_popup.js'); ?>"></script>
```

now my modal with the field displayed

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="form-group row">
     <label for="<?php echo $this->getDef('text_products_name') ; ?>" class="col-5 col-form-label"><?php echo $this->getDef('text_products_name') ; ?></label>
     <div class="col-md-7">
       <?php echo HTML::inputField('products_name', '', 'id="ajax_products_name" list="products_list" class="form-control"'); ?>
       <datalist id="products_list"></datalist>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <?php $products_ajax = $this->link('ajax/products.php'); ?>

<script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function(){
        // Add a keyup event listener to our input element
        document.getElementById('ajax_products_name').addEventListener("keyup", function(event){hinterManufacturer(event)});
        // create one global XHR object
        // so we can abort old requests when a new one is make
        window.hinterManufacturerXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    });

    // Autocomplete for form
    function hinterManufacturer(event) {
        var input = event.target;

        var ajax_products_name = document.getElementById('products_list'); //datalist id

        // minimum number of characters before we start to generate suggestions
        var min_characters = 0;

        if (!isNaN(input.value) || input.value.length < min_characters ) {
            return;
        } else {
            window.hinterManufacturerXHR.abort();
            window.hinterManufacturerXHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    var response = JSON.parse( this.responseText );

                    ajax_products_name.innerHTML = "";
                    response.forEach(function(item) {
// Create a new <option> element.
                        var option = document.createElement('option');
                        option.value = item.id + ' - ' + item.name;//get name
                        option.hidden = item.id; //get id

                        ajax_products_name.appendChild(option);
                    });
                }
            };

            window.hinterManufacturerXHR.open("GET", "<?php echo $products_ajax ; ?>?q=" + input.value, true);
            window.hinterManufacturerXHR.send()
        }
    }
</script>
```

Addedd js open modal

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#myModal").on("show.bs.modal", function(e) {
    const link = $(e.relatedTarget);
    $(this).find(".modal-body").load(link.attr("href"));
  });
});
```

there the screen shot of the result.

[console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdeDn.png)

Comment: How is the field getting inside the modal? when?

Comment: Look this line, it call the modal popup   <a href="<?php echo $this->link('SelectPopUpProducts'); ?>"  where there is the inputfield.

Comment: What I see is when I click on the module poup button the ajax is call : http://localhost/....../SelectPopUpProducts. Or it must be call when I fill he input field not before. maybe it's the problem

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the event `keyup` never fires because the input `ajax_products_name` doesn't exists until `shown.bs.modal` event is fired.

Try:

```
$("#myModal").on("shown.bs.modal", function(ev) {
  document.getElementById('ajax_products_name').addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    hinterManufacturer(event)
  });
})
```

Let's set up an example

```js
$('#exampleModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  // $('#myInput').trigger('focus')
  console.log("modal opened, *now* can addEventListener to stuff within modal")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Anyway, The idea is to do the `addEventListener` on the `ajax_products_name` only after it's loaded. So given your new snippet, try this:

```
// instead of 
$(this).find(".modal-body").load(link.attr("href"));


// do:
$(this).find(".modal-body").load(link.attr("href"), function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {
  if (statusTxt == "success") {

    // now that modal is opened AND content loaded
    document.getElementById('ajax_products_name').addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
      hinterManufacturer(event)
    })
  }
});
```

Comment: Where inside the script I need to change . The script must functional after the modal is loaded and not before, I suppose

Comment: thank thre my js open the pop up : see above screenshot